# How can I resize a TinyMCE popup when a select input changes?

Tags: resize, popup, tinymce

I have a TinyMCE Popup that shows/hides some elements when a select input changes. Is there a way I can resize the popup to reflect the new height of the body instead of forcing the user to resize the popup themselves?

`TinyMCEPopup.resizeToInnerSize();` always resizes the popup to the original size, not the new size (it cuts off the elements that were shown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding a command like so while creating the plugin:

```
ed.addCommand( 'PluginName_Resize', function( ui, v ) {
    ed.windowManager.params.mce_height = v.height + 10;
} );
```

Made the body element have the id `body-id` (`<body id="body-id">...</body>`)

And then when the select input changes:

```
var window = tinyMCEPopup.dom.getSize( 'body-id' );
tinyMCEPopup.execCommand( 'PluginName_Resize', false, { height : window.h } );
tinyMCEPopup.resizeToInnerSize();
```